# SwiftUI dismiss all active presented view controls and pop to root view controller

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to dismiss all active presented view controllers and pushed view controllers, but I'm facing some issue and not getting expected output.

ContentView -> Pushed(LoginView) -> Presented(HomeView) -> Expected back to (ContentView) directly without any animation lags and without showing intermediate animations. It should directly show content view.

here is my code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct FirstView: View {
    @State var showLoginView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 16) {
                Text("FirstView View")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                NavigationLink( destination: SecondView(), isActive: $showLoginView, label: {
                    Text("Show SecondView")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    
    @State var showHomeView = false
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 16) {
            Text("Second View")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(Color(.systemPurple))
            Button(action: { showHomeView = true }, label: {
                Text("Show ThirdView")
                    .padding()
            })
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showHomeView, onDismiss: { presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() }) {
            ThirdView()
        }
    }
}

struct ThirdView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @State var showFormView = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 16) {
            Text("Third View")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(Color(.systemTeal))
            Button(action: {
                showFormView = true
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }, label: {
                Text("Back to FirstView")
                    .padding()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not germane to the issue, but have you considered reworking the logic of your application to show LoginView / HomeView based on whether your user is logged in instead of showing HomeView as a nested view of LoginView? As you might know, SwiftUI follows a different data paradigm than Cocoa. You modify data, and the UI updates based on that state. And a HomeView isn't typically a nested view from Login.

Comment: I just named randomly.  As I mentioned `View1 -> PushTo(View2) -> Present(View3) -> BackTo(V1)` without showing intermediate animation.